# Razor helpers as editor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to use razor `@helper` methods as Editor Templates, removing the need to separate the template from the view (in one-use scenarios)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Custom templates are defined in a separate file, but I agree that such functionality would be handy.